# Draft.js import and export HTML with classname

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am adding some custom code to Draft.js. The issue that I am having is that when I import the HTML with a classname, the class is lost, and I need it to render the styling of the content. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-draft-wysiwyg-editor-forked-s0jid4?file=/index.js) is the project and here is how I am importing it:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
const ss = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  convertFromHTML('<p class="firstElement">Test</p>')
);
this.state = {
  editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ss)
};
```

}

How can I export the content maintaining "firstElement" in the first paragraph?

Thanks

Comment: draft.js is not a html editor. you need handle model convert between draft.js and html.

Comment: @JiangYD do you know if there is a way to import and preserve the class name of the HTML tags?